# Erro ao listar arquivo FTP

Tags: java

Boa noite pessoal, estou tentando fazer um programinha simples que lista os arquivos de um diretório FTP, sendo que está ocorrendo erro.

```
package br.com.java;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.SocketException;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;

public class FTPConnect {

public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException, IOException{
    // TODO code application logic here
    FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
    ftp.connect("ftp.endereco.com.br");
    ftp.login("usuario","senha");
    if(FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(ftp.getReplyCode()) ){
        System.out.println("Conectado!!");
        ftp.enterLocalActiveMode();
    }

    ftp.changeWorkingDirectory("/pasta/subpasta");
    System.out.println(ftp.getReplyString());
    System.out.println("porta: " + ftp.getDefaultPort());

    try {
        String[] arq = ftp.listNames();
        System.out.println("Listando arquivos \n");
        for (String f : arq){
            System.out.println(f);
        }
        ftp.logout();
        ftp.disconnect();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }catch (SocketException es){
        System.out.println(es.getMessage());
    }
}

 }
```

O resultado de saída é:

> ```
> run:
> Conectado!!
> 250 CWD command successful
>
> porta: 21
> Listando arquivos 
>
> null
> CONSTRUÍDO COM SUCESSO (tempo total: 0 segundos)
> ```

Alguém tem ideia do que pode estar acontecendo?

Answer (score 0):

O problema não aparenta ser Java e sim na permissão do usuário no servidor, 
O usuário pode não ter acesso para listar, verifique online no https://pt.infobyip.com/ftptest.php |Se tiveres acesso ao servidor e ele for Linux, execute o comando sudo chmod 777 /home/usuario/pasta_ftp
outro detalhe é a configuração do firewall porta 20 (dados).

Comment: Quando tento fazer pelo CMD a informação que aparece é esta:
`ftp> ls 
500 PORT/EPRT (Active Mode/Extended Active Mode) is not supported. Use PASV/EPSV
 instead of this
425 Unable to build data connection: Invalid argument
ftp> pasv
Comando inválido.
ftp>`

Comment: Pessoal, consegui resolver a questão alterando `ftp.enterLocalActiveMode();` para `ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();`